# How to validate domain objects in DDD architecture?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, domain-driven-design, getter-setter

I have found different ways of modelling the Domain Driven Architecture from different sources. But as a best practice, is it best to place the validations of an object in it's property setters keeping the setters private? Or to make the property itself private and perform validations in the constructor?

```
private string _lastName;
public string LastName
{
      get 
      {
        return this._lastName;
      }
      set
      {
        if(value == null)
        {
          return;
          //or throw exception
        } 

        _lastName = value;
      }
```

Please correct me if I am wrong in any way.

Comment: Meh tbh this has a distinct code smell. I'd define some common attribute based validators per each model, and then have convention based model initialisation.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, initially properties by DDD should be set in constructor and have private set method with validation inside(if required, some more complicated validations can be done in constructor (if it requires passing services etc.)).

If your domain logic requires to update some properties after object is created, you have two options:

1. Add Method `UpdateMyProperty()`
2. Use the same property with public setter `public MyProperty{public get; public set;}`

it depends on how complicated your domain logic is. If it requires other services use option 1 because you can pass services as arguments. If it is just a simple value update, use option 2

Comment: According to option 2, there is no encapsulation right? Beacuse from a service the property can be set by just assigning a value to it as it's setter is public.

Comment: Yes, probably encapsulation is a little bit minimized and property setters should not be used in more complicated logic. In some other languages only methods could be used in similar situations. But as C# has this properties feature I don't see any reasons why don't use it instead of methods, of course, for really simple updates.